# Postgresql copy CSV format, double quote escape not working

Tags: postgresql, csv

Running into an issue with copying the following data into a DB

`1, ab\"c`

I receive an unterminated quote error when running the following SQL

`copy table_name from sample.tsv CSV DELIMITER ',' QUOTE '"' ESCAPE E'\\'`

Based on the postgresql documentation I expect the escape parameter to be used to escape the quotation character but it's not working. Would like to see if there's a solution to this issue without reformatting the data, or changing the quote character.

Comment: **To your question add**: 1) A complete sample of the input data. e.g. the complete row and multiple rows. 2) Is the `\` in`\"c` something you are adding to the original data?

Answer (score 0):

try this. Because if quote is ", then it will mix with double quote in (ab"c).

```
copy table_name from 'sample.tsv' (FORMAT CSV, QUOTE '''', DELIMITER ',',ESCAPE E'\\');
```

Answer (score 0):

It is expecting to find escaped quotes only inside quotes, so the command you show would work for `1,"ab\"c"` but not for what you have.

The command that would work for the data you show is:

```
copy table_name from sample.tsv DELIMITER ','
```

But it is not likely to work for the rest of your data.